# convergence of a numerical method

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

given a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ in of class $C^3$. We suppose that there exists $s\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(s)=0$ and $f'(s)\neq 0$. Let $\beta$ be a real number s.t. $\beta \neq 0$. We define the function:$$\phi(x)=\begin{cases}x-\beta\frac{f(x)}{f(x+\beta f(x))-f(x)}\quad& \text{if the dominator is not null}\\ x \quad& \text{else}\end{cases}
$$
Show that there exists a neighborhood $V(s)$ of $s$ such that the procedure :
$$\begin{cases} x_0\in V(s)\ given\\ x_{n+1}=\phi(x_n),\quad n\geq 0\end{cases}$$ 
defines a convergent sequence $(x_n)_n$ to $s$.

I tried to show that $\phi$ is a contraction mapping by proving that $|\phi'(s)|<1$ but I found a problem in calculating the derivative in the point $s$. Does any one have an idea or a hint, I'll be grateful ! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is the function definition correct? To be some kind of secant or discretized Newton method, you would need the square of $f$, $$x_+=x-\frac{βf(x)^2}{f(x+βf(x))-f(x)}=x-\frac{f(x)}{\frac{f(x+[βf(x)])-f(x)}{[βf(x)]}}=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x+\thetaβf(x))}.$$

Comment: Indeed, the definition seems wrong. When $x$ is near $s$, the denominator is approximately $\beta f(x) f'(x) $. As a result, $\phi(x) $ is not close to $x$. This can't converge.